# How many voltage and amps to charge a 3.8 V 2200 mAh cellphone battery?

Tags: voltage, amperage, batteries

My charging port is broken. Need to make a charger, thanks for help.

Comment: This is not simple. You need to be very careful because the battery can explode or burst into flames. What level of experience do you have and what tools and components do you have. [Edit] this into your question.

Comment: "how to charge a lithium battery" has been asked really dozens, if not hundreds of times on here. You'll find a lot of answers that explain why that isn't an easy task, and what components to use to not make it a fire bomb.

Comment: im using a steup power supply module boost converter

Comment: You are not listening. If you had the knowledge to do this safely you wouldn't need to ask about this. It's the same for high voltage transformerless power droppers - if you need to ask it's too dangerous because you are not considering the fuller picture.

Comment: Look at some of [these}(https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=charging+lithium+4.2+charger)  that look useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the maximum voltage for a Li-Ion cell is around 4.2V and you should never go above that.
 Also, you have to limit the current so that neither the cell nor the charger will be damaged.
Normally, the charging current shouldn't be more than the rated capacity without the "h" in it (for 1Ah cell it takes 1 hour to charge it at 1C rate or at 1A charging current), so the 2200mAh (2.2Ah) cell in your case should not be charged with more than 2.2A.
It is even better to limit it to half the capacity or "C" rate, in this case 1.1A. You will not go wrong if you limit it to 500mA or 0.5A. A lower current will not cause damage, but a higher one can.
 The time it takes to charge a Li-Ion cell is its capacity divided by the charging current:
a) t=C/I
b) hours=Ah/A
c) charging time in hours = capacity in Ampere-hours / charging current in amperes
 So, your cell should be full after 1 hour if charged at 2.2A, or after 2 hours if charged at 1.1A, and so on.

Once again, the most important thing is that the voltage applied to the cell is never more than 4.2V.

Also, you should never leave a Li-Ion cell/battery to charge for many hours. It should be disconnected as soon as it is charged, as it doesn't absorb "trickle" charge as the nickel and lead based cells do.

Comment: Is it safe to use this? https://shopee.ph/Ready-Stock%E2%9C%BF-5V-to-3.3V-9V-12V-24V-DC-DC-USB-Step-up-Power-Supply-Module-Boost-Converter-i.112452154.2752003955

Comment: For charging a Li-Ion cell? No. The voltage needs to be REDUCED from 5V, not RAISED/BOOSTED.

Comment: I mean the input is 5V then i ill adjust the voltage to 4 volts to charge the battery

Comment: That is a BOOST converter, which means it is meant to RAISE the voltage. You need a BUCK or DOWN converter. There is a CC/CV 5A DC-DC converter on AliExpress fairly cheap, and you can adjust the constant (or maximum) current and the maximum voltage output, which is perfect for charging Li-ION (just don't forget you still need to disconnect after the battery is full!).